# I need a php function for dates

Tags: php

Example : 
Let say today is 3 Feb (first friday of the month)
then we have to find the dates like 
1 - 3 march (first friday of march )
2 - 7 april  (first friday of april)
and so on for the complete year

if today date is 28 feb (fourth tuesday of feb)
then expection is 
1 - 28 march (4th tuesday of march)
2 - 25 april (4th tuesday of april)
and so on for the complete year

Please suggest.[image]

Comment: Please, provide your code attempt. Actually your question is [Off-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as it is only a code request.

Comment: What Have You Tried So Far? Please Provide Your **Tried Code**.

Comment: I have number of weeks let say Today is 2017-05-27 so the week number is 4 and day is saturday so now I want a date function to get the same week number and day for the next month.

Answer (score -2):

the php DateTime object is easy use for handling dates. Check out the phpnet http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php here and tell me if it is helping your problem.

Comment: Let me elaborate more
 
I have number of weeks let say Today is 2017-05-27 so the week number is 4 and day is saturday so now I want a date function to get the same week number and day for the next month.

Comment: I found the solution via date functions, Thanks for all your help.